# How to get API status code from the header in angular, and API call type is document, and in response getting HTML content

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redash

Below is my HTML iframe code

```
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="safeUrl && !reportError">
    <div class="row">
        <iframe [src]="safeUrl" class="w-100" style="height:480px"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

and url is for iframe
safeUrl = `${myURL}`;

I want API status code from the header, My API type is document. Actually I am using redash report in angular, So If iframe URL throwing error that error I am not getting in response, In response I am getting HTML content.